# Convert string value to integer while aggregating mongodb document using php

Tags: php, string, mongodb, integer

I have a collection with a weather data - one document by day. I have to show an average value by month. Here is my aggregation mongo shell query:

```
db.weather.aggregate([{$match : { month : "11", year : "2013"}},
{ $group : { _id : 0, maxTempAvg : { $avg : "$maxtemp" } } }])
```

The problem is that `maxtemp` is a string, so my result is `0`.

How can I convert it to integer without updating the datatype of `maxtemp` in the db? Is there a solution to make it with php?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why store a number as a string? unless it's HUGE number that exceeds the db's capabilities, there's no point in destroying a fundamental aspect of the data.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I can only read the db, so I have to find a workaround... :)

Answer (score 0):

The first approach would be to try to speak with people maintaining database and who has write access and to persuade him to change the schema.

The second would be to rewrite your query with mapreduce because there you use javascript functions like parseInt(). And you can use php driver to run mapreduce queries.